# Python: Splitting txt file by tab

Tags: python, list, split, tabs

first off new to python and not good at it... I am trying to open a txt file called bestsellers.txt. In the text file it is split by a tab character for example,

```
1st to Die    James Patterson    Little, Brown    3/25/2001    Fiction
```

So, after Die it is tab spaced same with after patterson and brown and 2001
All I have right now is

```
openBook = open('bestsellers.txt', 'r')
booklist = openBook.split('\t')
```

But, it doesn't seem to work, suggestions on what to do? I have to keep it simple. 
I know this is probably a dumb question as well, so I apologize...

Answer (score 7):

To split at each tab, iterate over the file like so:

```
data = [i.strip('\n').split('\t') for i in open('bestsellers.txt')]
```

Answer (score 1):

`openBook` is a file, not a string. Even if it were a string, you'd want to iterate over the lines, and split each line on the tabs. So something like this:

```
with open("bestsellers.txt") as bookfile:
    for line in bookfile:
        fields = line.split("\t")
        # now do something with this book's fields
```

But a better solution is to not reinvent the wheel and instead use the `csv` module, which is intended for reading various kinds of text files.

Answer (score 0):

You will need something along these  lines:

```
for line in open(document).readlines():
    line.split("\t")
```