# How to read words seperated by spaces as a single value

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a .txt file in python and store the result in a list. My txt file looks something like this:

```
Roll no         12
Name            Abc
Date of birth   11/11/90
```

expected output in a list:

```
['Roll no','12','Name','Abc','Date of birth','11/11/90']
```

the output I get after using readLines():

```
['Roll','no','12','Name','Abc','Date','of','birth','11/11/90']
```

Comment: Are all of the words separated by spaces? If there is not some other type of white space (like a Tab character) between columns, I don't see how your program would know that some of the words belong together.

Comment: @jalynn2 looks like it was a question formatting problem. "Roll no    12" is all on one line.

Comment: Not all of the words are separated by spaces, there are some individual words such as "Name" in the above example. And yes there's tab between columns.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46918404/python-splitting-txt-file-by-tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing actual code, it's difficult to know exactly what's gone wrong here.

`readlines` will split a file on a newline delimiter. For complete cross-platform compatibility, open files in the "universal" compatibility mode (PEP-278 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/), which avoids questions about whether your lines end in '\n', '\r\n', or some other variation (depends on whether you're on a DOS or Unix-like system):

```
with open('input.txt', 'rU') as t:
    lines = t.readlines()
```

You can then take the set of lines and, given that your input uses a tab delimiter, split each line into a key/value pair:

```
results = list()
for line in lines:
    key,value = line.strip().split('\t')
    results.append(key)
    results.append(value)
```

There are ways to collapse this down into a list comprehension, but the above is a very explicit example of how to achieve your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Since the fields are tab-delimited, you can simply split each line by tabs. The example below assumes that the file is opened as `file`:

```
[token for line in file for token in line.rstrip().split('\t')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to read the lines, and then use map() with strip() :

data4.txt :

```
Roll no   12
Name      Abc
Date of birth   11/11/90
```

Code :

```
fileName = 'data\data4.txt'
with open(fileName) as f:
  lines= f.readlines()

lines= map(lambda s: s.strip(), lines)
list(lines)
```

Result :

```
['Roll no   12', 'Name      Abc', 'Date of birth   11/11/90']
```

To Remove 12, Abc and 11/11/90 :

```
fileName = 'data\data4.txt'
with open(fileName) as f:
  lines= f.readlines()

lines= map(lambda s: s.strip(), lines)
lines = [x.split(' ')[:-1] for x in lines]

Result=[]
for line in lines:
    Result.append(' '.join(line).strip())

Result
```

Result :

```
['Roll no', 'Name', 'Date of birth']
```

Comment: This looks promising. Is there any way I can get rid of 12, Abc, 11/11/90?