# Separation by tab when reading from txt-file not working properly

Tags: python

I have this code in my main program:

```
def readfile(file):
  with open(file, encoding="utf-8") as file:
    list = []
    for row in file:
      temp = row.split("\t")
      temp[1] = temp[1].strip()
      list.append(temp)
    return list
```

and I want to read from a txt file in this format:

```
21-10-22  2348.84
21-10-25  2330.13
21-10-26  2344.20
21-10-27  2323.17
21-10-28  2313.24
21-10-29  2290.85
21-11-01  2302.26
21-11-02  2302.67
21-11-03  2317.67
21-11-04  2330.07
21-11-05  2324.90
21-11-08  2331.84
21-11-09  2327.12
21-11-10  2331.42
21-11-11  2346.46
21-11-12  2365.45
21-11-15  2374.47
21-11-16  2385.63
21-11-17  2384.10
21-11-18  2373.04
21-11-19  2373.92
21-11-22  2368.71
```

I want to return a list with each value in the right hand column of the text file. But when I do print(readfile("file.txt")) it just prints "['21-10-22  2348.84\n']" and then

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 51, in readfile
    temp[1] = temp[1].strip()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why does only the first row get stored in the list? What is the error in the code? I can't find it...

Comment: Looks like at leat one of the lines contains no \t character, so `row.split("\t")` returns a list of length one. This means `temp[1]` does not exist.

Comment: Are you sure there are tabs? The exception throws on the very first line.

Comment: well, the sample text file given has no tabs, but double space as separator. Either change text file to use tab, or just use row.split() and see.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Splitting txt file by tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46918404/python-splitting-txt-file-by-tab)

Answer (score 0):

Use `row.split()` instead of `row.split("\t")`. [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function without argument, takes care of white spaces (exactly what you need). It seems like there is no `\t` in the file.

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

> If sep is not specified or is `None`, a different splitting algorithm is
> applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single
> separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start
> or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace.

In addition, you need to modify(and simplify) your code:

```
def readfile(file):
    with open(file, encoding="utf-8") as file:
        return [line.split()[1] for line in file]

print(readfile('txttt.txt'))
```

<sub>* Do not use built-in names like "list" for your variables.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Using `.split()` without parameters splits the row on all whitespace. This also strips the newline at the end. Therefore, you could simplify your code to this:

```py
def readfile(file):
  with open(file, encoding="utf-8") as file:
    list = []
    for row in file:
      temp = row.split()
      list.append(temp[1])
    return list
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the change you need: `split` on spaces rather than `\t`, see the below updated code. Also never use the built-ins like `list` etc as variable names

```
def readfile(file):
  with open(file, encoding="utf-8") as file:
    out_list = []
    for row in file:
      temp = row.split()    # Split on space rather than \t
      temp[1] = temp[1].strip()
      out_list.append(temp[1])
    return out_list
```

Comment: This will return ['21-10-22', '2348.84'],  instead of only the right hand column (OP) as need.

Comment: Updated the code, thanks for pointing it out..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *List Comprehension* approach.

```
def readfile(file):
  with open(file, encoding="utf-8") as file:
    return [row.split()[1] for row in file]
```

[**Output**]

```
['2348.84', '2330.13', '2344.20', '2323.17', '2313.24', '2290.85', '2302.26', '2302.67', '2317.67', '2330.07', '2324.90', '2331.84', '2327.12', '2331.42', '2346.46', '2365.45', '2374.47', '2385.63', '2384.10', '2373.04', '2373.92', '2368.71']
```